# Runtime error on a Codechef problem: modified Fibonacci series. What's the mistake?

Tags: c, fibonacci

I'm trying to solve a problem on codechef, here's the link:

> https://www.codechef.com/problems/KFIB

The given problem statement is:

> Chef recently had been studying about Fibonacci numbers and wrote a code to print out the k-th term of the Fibonacci series (1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13….). He was wondering whether he could write a program to generate the k-th term for similar series. More specifically:
>
> - T(n, k) is 1 if n <= k and
> - T(n, k) = T(n-1, k) + T(n-2, k) + T(n-3, k) … + T(n-k, k) if n > k.
>
> Given n and k, output T(n, k) % (1000000007) as the answer could be very large
>
> Input : Two integers, N and K
>
> Output : One integer, the nth term of the series mod 1000000007
>
> Constraints : 1 ≤ N, K ≤ 2*10<sup>5</sup>

example:

> Input: 7 5
>
> Output: 9
>
> The series is as follows {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 9}

```
 void fibo(int n, unsigned long k) {
     unsigned long *a, c;

     a = (unsigned long *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long) * k);

     for (unsigned long i = 0; i < k; i++) {  //T(n,k)=1 when n<=k
         *(a + i)=1;
     }

     for (unsigned long m = 0; m < n - 1; m++) {
         c = *(a);
         for (unsigned long j = 0; j < k - 1; j++) {
             *(a + j) = *(a + j + 1);
             c = c + *(a + j);
         }
         *(a + k - 1) = c;
     }
     printf("%d ", *(a) % 1000000007);
}
```

This works with smaller values but not with very large values. I got the result of the example but when I enter the values `200000 500`, I get incorrect answers

Comment: Side note: `*(a+i)` can be replaced with `a[i]`, looks like case of overflow.

Comment: Does substituting `unsigned long` for `unsigned long long` would work? The output is `%1000000007`. Do you think you can compute `%` each time you  increment `c`, like `c += a[j]; c %= 1000000007`?  That way the value will always stay below `%1000000007` and the overflow will not happen. You can output `c` values and see if it overflows. | The `a` is `malloc`-ed but never `free`-ed. Your program leaks memory.

Comment: What do you mean by `2*105`, `2^105` ? if yes even integer `long long` on 64bits are not enough long so you cannot get them as even `long long` parameter. Please clarify

Comment: @bruno it will be 2*10^5 sorry about that

Comment: @kiranBiradar could you please explain the difference?

Comment: @KamilCuk i tried both and it certainly improved the results but im still getting errors

Comment: @AnkitaPaul `a[i]` is more readable than `*(a+i)`, that is the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid overflow, you can change below statement

```
c=c+*(a+j);
```

To

```
c=(c+*(a+j))%1000000007;
```

That means only the remainder will be keep in your heap. This won't impact the final results.

Here is the updated code and compiled by clang.(updated according to @bruno's comments)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIVIDER 1000000007ul
#define U4 unsigned long

U4 fibo(U4 n,U4 k)
{
    U4 *a,c ;
    if(n<=k) return 1;

    a= (U4*) malloc (sizeof(U4)*k);

    for (U4 i=0;i<k;i++)   //T(n,k)=1 when n<=k
    {
        *(a+i)=1;
    }

    for (U4 m=k;m<n; m++)
    {
        c=*(a);
        for (U4 j=0;j<k-1;j++)
        {
          *(a+j)= *(a+j+1);
          c=(c+*(a+j))%DIVIDER;
        }
        *(a+k-1)=c;
    }
    free(a);
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    U4 n, k;
    char *endptr;
    if(argc <= 2){
        printf("usage: t.exe n k");
        return 0;
    }
    n = strtoul(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
    k = strtoul(argv[2], &endptr, 10);
    printf("%lu", fibo(n,k));
}
```

Compiler command:

```
$ clang test.c -o test.exe
$ test.exe 200000 500
80391289
```

Comment: I encourage you to replace _1000000007_ by _1000000007ul_, and to add `free(a);` ;-) Warning you also do `m<n` while one is signed and not the other

Comment: @Minigjian Zhou Thanks that helped me out a bit but i am still getting "non zero exit code" on certain test cases. ( I'm trying this on a practice problem on codechef and i cannot pass all the sub-tasks.)

Comment: @AnkitaPaul with which inputs ? None of us have magic crystal ball to guess what you do not say ^^

Comment: @bruno sorry i'm new to this. The inputs are not given to us. When i submit they run it with their test cases and show if it works or not. I edited the post and added a link to the actual problem statement if that helps.

Comment: @bruno, thank you for your suggestion. I update code and post full code.

Comment: @AnkitaPaul unfortunately that does not indicate the wrong cases (if I read well)

Comment: `#define U4 unsigned long` is bad style: use a `typedef` instead of a preprocessor macro, and do not assume `long` is 4 bytes. For example `long` is 8 bytes on 64-bit linux systems. If you really want shorter type names, use `typedef unsigned long ulong;`

Comment: @AnkitaPaul: add `return 0;` at the end of the `main()` function. You might also use `printf("%lu\n", fibo(n, k));` to finish the output with a newline.

Comment: @chqrlie that return 0 solved another part of the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you compute the value modulo `ULONG_MAX` and reduce the result modulo `1000000007` at the end. This does not give the correct result. You must reduce modulo `1000000007` at each step to avoid potential arithmetic overflow (which does not cause undefined behavior for type `unsigned long` but gives a different result from the expected one).

Here is a modified version of your code with a faster alternative (more than twice as fast on my laptop):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIVIDER 1000000007ul

unsigned long fibo(unsigned long n, unsigned long k) {
    unsigned long c = 1;

    if (n > k) {
        unsigned long *a = (unsigned long *)malloc(sizeof(*a) * k);

        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < k; i++) {  //T(n,k)=1 when n<=k
            a[i] = 1;
        }
        for (unsigned long m = k; m < n; m++) {
            c = a[0];
            for (unsigned long j = 0; j < k - 1; j++) {
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
#if 0
                // slower version using modulo
                c = (c + a[j]) % DIVIDER;
#else
                // faster version with a test
                if ((c += a[j]) >= DIVIDER)
                    c -= DIVIDER;
#endif
            }
            a[k - 1] = c;
        }
        free(a);
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc <= 2) {
        printf("usage: fibo n k");
        return 1;
    } else {
        unsigned long n = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        unsigned long k = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 10);
        printf("%lu\n", fibo(n, k));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ time ./fibo 200000 100000
871925546

real    0m34.667s
user    0m34.288s
sys     0m0.113s

$ time ./fibo-faster 200000 100000
871925546

real    0m15.073s
user    0m14.846s
sys     0m0.064s
```

Given the restrictions on input values:

- the values of `T(n, k)` are in the range [0..1000000006] which fits in an `int32_t`.
- the sum of `k` terms is in the range [0..200000*1000000006] which fits in an `int64_t`.
- hence we can compute the next term in 64 bits and use a single modulo on the result.

This gives an even faster version (more than 3 times faster):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIVIDER 1000000007

uint32_t fibo(uint32_t n, uint32_t k) {
    uint32_t c = 1;

    if (n > k) {
        uint32_t *a = (uint32_t *)malloc(sizeof(*a) * k);
        uint64_t temp;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < k; i++) {  //T(n,k)=1 when n<=k
            a[i] = 1;
        }
        for (uint32_t m = k; m < n; m++) {
            temp = a[0];
            for (uint32_t j = 0; j < k - 1; j++) {
                temp += a[j] = a[j + 1];
            }
            a[k - 1] = c = temp % DIVIDER;
        }
        free(a);
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc <= 2) {
        printf("usage: fibo n k");
        return 1;
    } else {
        uint32_t n = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        uint32_t k = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 10);
        printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)fibo(n, k));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ time ./fibo-faster 200000 100000
871925546

real    0m3.854s
user    0m3.800s
sys     0m0.018s
```

Comment: thank you, that was helpful but i guess the main problem im facing right now is the amount of memory it takes up and non zero exit code

Comment: @AnkitaPaul:  non zero exit code is solved with `return 0;` from `main()`. The amont of memory does not seem so large. Using any less memory would require a lot longer to compute.